# Can not block IP from 3g on Nginx

Tags: nginx, 3g-network

I have a problem with block IP from Nginx, I test block IP 113.185.75.235 ( and range of 75.235 ), I used the code bellow:

```
location / {
deny 113.185.75.235;
deny 113.185.75.0/24;
}
```

It's work good if use LAN NETWORK, but use 3g/4g, deny not effective.

Comment: When you use 3g/4g, you have the same IP?

Comment: I test other IP man.

Comment: I mean, is the IP you have when using 3g/4g in the block 113.185.75.0/24 ? I usually have different IP when using 3g/4g and LAN network.

Comment: Like, I have 81.120.12.15 when using LAN and 91.130.120.18 on 3g/4g, they are not in the same block

Comment: I cannot find any other reason :) sorry (I think it's a SO rule to writing in English). The nginx configuration is ok.

Comment: Right man, I continue found the complete solutions, if found, I share You :D